# Why did the government not want Frank to fight?

Tags: plot-explanation, bloodsport

In [Bloodsport (1988)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092675/), when Frank's superiors find out he is going to Hong Kong to fight in the Kumite, they try to stop him. He evades Helmer and Rawlins (the agents who were sent to bring him back home) and gets to Hong Kong anyway, where Helmer and Rawlins try again to stop him and bring him back.

Why? "The US Governemnt has invested a lot of time and money into you and we don't want you getting hurt". What does that mean? Dux is a Captain which isn't low rank, but it isn't like a General. So why is he so special that they want to keep him from participating in the Kumite?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Frank Dux has stated (and this can be found on [his website](http://www.frankwdux.com/KogaRyu.html)) that he was an Elite Operative with super-high security clearance.  Further, he states that his military record has been sealed, even impervious to the FOIA (Freedom Of Information Act) due to covert operations in Russia and his involvement in Iran/Contra.  Someone this important to the military would most certainly be dissuaded from participating in an event that could potentially lead to death.

Personally, I think the whole thing is a work of fiction.  In fact, it has been [claimed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Dux#Martial_arts_career) that the "Kumite" had his own house as an address, and the trophy he won was purchased at a trophy shop (with a receipt provided).  Dux insists those claims are meant to discredit him.

The [Los Angeles Times](http://articles.latimes.com/1988-05-01/local/me-3111_1_american-martial-arts) ran an article in 1988 that stated he was a complete fraud.

Comment: I only looked at the wikipedia page. Completely missed his website.